# Iterating over a hashmap to populate Accordion component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the Accordion component from primereact that works fine with simple text, but I'm trying to implement the accordion so that it is populated by a hashmap, each key will be the header and the scrolling down text would be the value. I'm also using npm hashmap.

The hashmap is correct I've logged it and it has all the elements needed.

Here is the code that doesn't show anything for whatever reasons, it doesn't even console.log:

```
 return (
        <div className="accordion-demo">
            <div className="card">
                <h5>Medical appointment</h5>
                <Accordion activeIndex={0}>
                    {(() => {
                        for (const pair of hashMapAppointment) {
                            console.log("key" + pair.key);
                            console.log("value" + pair.value);
                            <AccordionTab header={pair.key}>
                                <p>{pair.value}</p>
                            </AccordionTab>
                        }
                    }
                     ) }
                </Accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `Object.entries`

```
{
  Object.entries(hashMapAppointment).map(([key, value]) => {
    console.log("key" + key);
    console.log("value" + value);
    return (
      <AccordionTab header={key} key={key}>
        <p>{value}</p>
      </AccordionTab>
    );
  });
}
```